# Count word in file Java8 using reduce method

Tags: java, java-stream, reduce

I want to count the occurence of word in file with reduce in java8 any help appreciated i do not want to use Collector or Map so far my code is ;

```
filecontent.flatMap(line->Stream.of(line.split("\\s+")))
                       .map(String::toLowerCase)
                       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));   
  //here I want to replace colect() with reduce
```

Comment: Why would you want to use `reduce()` when `collect()` works fine?

Comment: I just want @daniu to use it like google's map and reduce

Comment: I don't get that motivation. But yeah, it seems people have found a way if I look at the answers.

Answer (score 1):

First you should provide a complete compilable example in your question, like:

```
Stream<String> filecontent = Stream.of("foo in bar is foo", "bar in bar is not foo");
Map<String, Long> result = filecontent.flatMap(line -> Stream.of(line.split("\\s+")))
    .map(String::toLowerCase)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Then to reduce, you need to use Map objects to reduce (For brevity using a Java HashMap, which is not the most efficient datastructure for this case):

```
Stream<String> filecontent = Stream.of("foo in bar is foo", "bar in bar is not foo");
Map<String, Long> result = filecontent.flatMap(line -> Stream.of(line.split("\\s+")))
    .map((word) -> singletonMap(word.toLowerCase(), 1L))
    .reduce(new HashMap<>(), (map1, map2) -> {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry: map2.entrySet()) {
            map1.put(entry.getKey(), map1.getOrDefault(entry.getKey(), 0L) + entry.getValue());
        }
        return map1;
    });
```

This will create a new empty HashMap first, then for each new word a singleton Hashmap, and in each reduce step merge such a singleton map into the original hashmap. If you want to do this using a parallel stream, you need to create a fresh map in the reduce step:

```
        Map<String, Long> tempResult = new HashMap<>(map1);
        for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry: map2.entrySet()) {
            tempResult.put(entry.getKey(), map1.getOrDefault(entry.getKey(), 0L) + entry.getValue());
        }
        return tempResult;
```

Comment: instead of `Arrays.asList(...).stream()` just directly use `Stream.of(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @tkruse's answer I came up with following snippet:

```
Stream<String> fileContent = Stream.of("foo in bar is foo", "bar in bar is not foo");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
Map<String, Long> result = fileContent
    .flatMap(pattern::splitAsStream)
    .reduce(new HashMap<String, Long>(), (map, word) -> {
        map.merge(word, 1L, Long::sum);
        return map;
    }, (left, right) -> {
        right.forEach((key , count ) -> left.merge(key, count, Long::sum));
        return left;
    });
```

Note the second line which creates a pattern which is then used in the stream to split the lines.